# Prestashop HelpForm type switch in module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want create a input type switch in my backend module in prestashop 1.6.
I write this and work

```
array(
    'type' => 'switch',
    'label' => $this->l('Label'),
    'name' => 'PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH',
    'is_bool' => true,
    'desc' => $this->l('Description'),
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'active_on',
            'value' => true,
            'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'active_off',
            'value' => false,
            'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
        )
    ),
)
```

But if i try with custom value e not boolean it not work

```
array(
    'type' => 'switch',
    'label' => $this->l('Label'),
    'name' => 'PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH',
    'is_bool' => false,
    'desc' => $this->l('Description'),
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'value1',
            'value' => 'value1',
            'label' => $this->l('value1')
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'value2',
            'value' => 'value2',
            'label' => $this->l('value2')
        )
    ),
)
```

In backend appear two boxes with labels value 'no'.
In HelperForm classes of prestashop there is no trace of input type switch.
The same code with type radio work, but i want a switch type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you can see here:
[image]
PrestaShop doesn't have possibility to use custom value in "switch" field.

Comment: It is in "themes/default/template/helpers/form/form.tpl"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change default switch values.

This is how you handle submit form:

```
public function getContent()
{
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitForm'))
    {
  $my_value = ( (int)Tools::getValue('PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH') == 1 ) ? 'value1' : 'value2';
  if (Configuration::updateValue('PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH', $my_value))
            $echo .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Value updated.'));

    }
    $echo .= $this->renderForm();

    return $echo;
}
```

You probably already have something like this:

```
public function renderForm()
{

    $fields_form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'input' => array(

        array(
            'type' => 'switch',
            'label' => $this->l('Label'),
            'name' => 'PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH',
            'is_bool' => true,
            'desc' => $this->l('Description'),
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 'active_on',
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => $this->l('Value1')
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 'active_off',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'label' => $this->l('Value2')
                )
            ),
        )
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            )
        ),
    );

    $helper = new HelperForm();
    $helper->module = $this;
    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $helper->table = $this->table;
    $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    $helper->default_form_language = $lang->id;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') ? Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') : 0;
    $this->fields_form = array();

    $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitForm';
    $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false).'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
        'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFieldsValues(),
        'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
        'id_language' => $this->context->language->id
    );

    return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
}
```

and loading the values:

```
public function getConfigFieldsValues()
{
    return array(
        'PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH' => Tools::getValue('PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH', Configuration::get('PRESTASHOP_INPUT_SWITCH') == 'value1' : 1 : 0),
    );
}
```

Comment: I had thought of this solution, but I can not change the label on the switch

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately prestashop doesn't support the custom value of switch but you can handle this like:

```
$config = Configuration::get('oneclickcheckout');
     $this->settings = Tools::unSerialize($config);
     $settings = $this->settings;
     if (isset($settings['Description']) && $settings['Description'] == 1) {

    }
```

Comment: My problem is not the custom value but custom label